# What chapter of the Seven Deadly Sins manga is Episode 20?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Alright so I am caught up with the anime but cannot wait for the next episode (currently on episode 20). What chapter would match the anime?

Comment: Season 1 or season 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you are currently on episode 20 and cannot wait for the next episode, I'm assuming that you are on season 2, so:

The 20th episode of Season 2 corresponds to the chapters **176, 177, 178, 179** of the manga.

Source:[Wiki](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_20)